# Passing a value to a low variable 'snippet'

Tags: low-variables

When using Low Variables as one would use embeds to include a block of code, is it possible to pass a variable into that code?

For instance,

```
{lv_mysnippet foo="bar"}
```

So that I can used the value of foo within the low variable?

Answer (score 1):

[Using preload-replace vars](http://gotolow.com/blog/snippets-and-preload-replace-variables) is possible, but the vars need to have early parsing enabled for it to work.

If you're using [the Textarea var type](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/types#textarea), you can also use Tag syntax (rather than the Variable syntax) and use the `preparse:my_var="value"` parameters, eg:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_textarea_var" preparse:myvar="foo"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that I can simply use {preload_replace}

```
{preload_replace myvar="foo"}

{lv_mysnippet}
```

This lets me use the value of myvar within {lv_mysnippet}